# Android HTTP/HTTPS network interception

Tags: android, runtime, interceptor, code-injection

Lately I did some iOS swizzling since there was no other way to solve a case that I needed, watching every HTTP/HTTPS network calls (monitoring) the application will make.

Now I would like to do the same thing for Android.

I'm thinking if there is the possibility to inject somehow code to some classes with my implementation or any similar way to add code in runtime so I can gather all the required information from all the network requests (url, start time, latency, request, response, body, data size, headers etc)

So I guess I will have to hook to the desired concrete classes and get informed when some specific methods are invoked in turn to calculate/record my info!

I don't know if there is a solution hooking up somehow to any interfaces/events etc. and get it done, first sight it doesn't seem to have something ready for this.

Comment: I'm not completely sure [these](http://serverfault.com/questions/248223/how-do-i-know-what-processes-are-using-the-network) will work, but they might. All that is left is creating some parser to examine the results.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Android Java programming and the question, which is strictly creating something in code that will serve as a solution to the problem.

Comment: [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) includes `netstat` command, which should do what you want. Android applications can run these commands and receive the results. I think this is legitimate and easiest way. [Here's how to write basic root application](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/how-to-build-an-android-app-part-2-writing-a-root-app-xda-tv/)